# Joining string in excel without manually create formula in each cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Suppose i have table as below in excel :

***Table Preview:***

[image]

Is there a way(formula or vba) to create data in `column3`, without manually create formula in each cell ?
now i use formula like this :

```
=B2&" "&B3&" "&B4
```

to create data in column3 manually.

> Note : I'm using MS Excel 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=IF(A2="","",TEXTJOIN(" ",1,IF(A2=LOOKUP(ROW(A$2:A$11),ROW(A$2:A$11)/(A$2:A$11<>""),A$2:A$11),B$2:B$11,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this formula works with no additional step

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the numbers 1..2..3 in column 1 for each of the entries you want to join, then maybe this will help:
https://www.howtoexcel.org/formulas/how-to-conditionally-concatenate-a-range-formula/

Be sure to use the array-formula for this

Willem

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the easiest answer to understand, its working but i need to add additional step(add same number for record that i want to join in column 1)